# form does not submit to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am trying to enter the information into a database, while uploading a file to a server and storing it's link in the database. At this point the file uploads, however no form data shows up in the database and returns an error message that the form cannot be submitted, however does not actually specify the error.

Any help would be amazing!!!

```
<?php

$dbc=mysql_connect('localhost', 'mgertenbach', 'mollyr');
mysql_select_db('mgertenbach', $dbc);


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //you needed to move this INSIDE the conditional.. you had it up at line 15 which... woudl cause the errors to show.
    $sqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO band_information
            VALUES ('{$_POST['bandname']}', '{$_FILES['bandphoto']['name']}', '{$_POST['bandbio']}', '{$_POST['bandcity']}', '{$_POST['bandstate']}', '{$_POST['bandzipcode']}', '{$_POST['bandgenre']}', '{$_POST['bandlink']}');";

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bandphoto']['tmp_name'], "C:\\HTML\\mgertenbach\\BAND\\photos\\{$_FILES['bandphoto']['name']}") && @mysql_query($sqlinsertString, $dbc)){
        print '<p>Thanks for submitting your band!</p>';
    } else {
        print '<p>Could not submit band because: <br/>' .
        mysql_error($dbc) . '</p>';
    }
}                   



?>

    <h3>Please fill out the following information.</h3>

    <form action="submitband.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset><legend>Who Are You?</legend>
            <label>Band Name: <input type="text" name="bandname" size="10"/></label>
            <br/><br/>

            <label>Link to Photo*: <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" /><input type="file" id="bandphoto" name="bandphoto" /></label>
            <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*image must be a square file
            <br/><br/>
            <label>Enter a short bio: <br/><textarea name="bandbio" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></label>
        </fieldset>
        <br/><br/> 
        <fieldset><legend>Where Are You From?</legend>
            <label>City: <input type="text" name="bandcity" size="10"/></label>
            <br/><br/>
            <label>State: 
                <select id="bandstate" name="bandstate">
                        <option value=""> </option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="NY">New York</option>
                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select></label>  
            <br/><br/>
            <label>Zipcode: <input type="text" name="bandzipcode" size="10"/></label>
        </fieldset>  
        <br/><br/>
        <fieldset><legend>What's Your Music Like?</legend>
            <label>Genre: 
                <select name="bandgenre">
                        <option value="country">Country</option>
                        <option value="electronic">Electronic</option>
                        <option value="folk">Folk</option>
                        <option value="indie">Indie</option>
                        <option value="punk">Punk</option>
                        <option value="rock">Rock</option>
                </select>
                </label>
            <br/><br/>
            <label>Share a link to where we can hear it: <input type="text" name="bandlink" size="40"/></label>
        </fieldset>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>          
    </form>
```

Comment: escape you values to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Also, probably not a good idea to broadcast your username + password to the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you have curly braces like this `'{$_POST['bandname']}'`

   This is PHP not bash so get rid of them.
2. > however does not actually specify the error

   Remove `@` from
   @mysql_query to see the error
3. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection as pointed out in the
   comment use parametrized query or PDO

Answer (score 0):

first, removing the @ beforre mysql_query will get you error messages. also you have two layers of single quotes in your code, this won't ever return any result:

```
$sqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO band_information
            VALUES ('{$_POST['bandname']}', '{$_FILES['bandphoto']['name']}', '{$_POST['bandbio']}', '{$_POST['bandcity']}', '{$_POST['bandstate']}', '{$_POST['bandzipcode']}', '{$_POST['bandgenre']}', '{$_POST['bandlink']}');";
```

moreover, you don't list the fields in which you will insert? not a problem, be sure each value fits the desired field type or the query will fail.
you have two ways of correcting the sql, either assign each value beforehand then use them:

```
$bandname = $_POST['bandname'];
$sqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO band_information VALUES ('$bandname', // etc
```

or get out of your double quote then put the variable:

```
$sqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO band_information VALUES ('" . $_POST['bandname'] . "','" .  $_FILES['bandphoto']['name'] . "','" .  $_POST['bandbio'] . "','" .  $_POST['bandcity'] . "','" .  $_POST['bandstate'] . "','" .  $_POST['bandzipcode'] . "','" .  $_POST['bandgenre'] . "','" .  $_POST['bandlink'] . "')";
```

oh and... I've no idea why there are curly braces? never used them in sql..

this if is hard to debug

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bandphoto']['tmp_name'], "C:\\HTML\\mgertenbach\\BAND\\photos\\{$_FILES['bandphoto']['name']}") && @mysql_query($sqlinsertString, $dbc))
```

this will have the same behavior if the sql is faulty or if the move_uploaded_file fails. moving files is notoriously a bitch because all those permissions problems. maybe try separing those:

```
if (mysql_query($sqlInsertString))
 {if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bandphoto']['tmp_name'], "C:\\HTML\\mgertenbach\\BAND\\photos\\{$_FILES['bandphoto']['name']}"))
   {echo 'both worked!';}}
  else
   {echo 'only the query worked';}
else
 {echo 'the query failed';}
```